# Trigger won't change Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a template for buttons in order to prevent the graying of the control when it is disabled, it is working just fine, but for some reason it won't change Backgrounds once I set a colour for it the Button Properties.

Here is the button I made:

> ```
>     <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TestButton">
>         <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
>         <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
>         <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="29px" />
>         <Setter Property="MinWidth"  Value="103px" />
>         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
>         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
>         <Setter Property="Template">
>             <Setter.Value>
>                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
>                     <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" x:Name="Border">
>                         <Border.Background>
>                             <SolidColorBrush  Color="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
>                         </Border.Background>
>                         <Border.BorderBrush>
>                             <SolidColorBrush  Color="Black" />
>                         </Border.BorderBrush>
>                         <Border.BorderThickness>
>                             <Thickness Top="0.75" Bottom="0.75" Right="0.75" Left="0.75"/>
>                         </Border.BorderThickness>
>                         <Border.CornerRadius>
>                             <CornerRadius TopLeft="3" TopRight="3" BottomLeft="3" BottomRight="3"/>
>                         </Border.CornerRadius>
>                         <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
>                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
>                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
>                         RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
>                     </Border>
>                     <!--Triggers-->
>                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
>                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E1F3FD" />
>                         </Trigger>
>                         <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
>                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C4E9FF" />
>                             <Setter Property="Effect">
>                                 <Setter.Value>
>                                     <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="500" ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
>                                 </Setter.Value>
>                             </Setter>
>                         </Trigger>
>                         <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
>                             <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Background}"/>
>                             <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
>                         </Trigger>
>                         <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"  >
>                             <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Background}" />
>                         </Trigger>
>                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
>                 </ControlTemplate>
>             </Setter.Value>
>         </Setter>
>     </Style>
> ```

When I call it gives me two diferent results, the one that works is the following:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TestButton}" Content="Button" Height="66" Name="button1" Width="149" Click="button1_Click" />
```

But when I add a Background to it, it stops changing Backgrounds for some reason:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TestButton}" Background="Orange" Content="Button" Height="66" Name="button1" Width="149" Click="button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Add the `Background="Orange"` to the Style and you should be good to go.

Comment: How? If I add it to the Button Style it doesn't work, and I don't want to add it into my template, since its supposed to be compatible with all colours since the user is going to define it.
What I mean is, that if the user changes the colour at runtime, the entire template should still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wont change the color because you "overlay" the color with the color you defined in MainWindow.xaml.

Its called dependency property value precedence.

To read more about it take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

What happens in your case is that you defined a background in style and in trigger but then you set the value in MainWindow. The value set in MainWindow is considered the local value and the ones set in style are "style - values".

If you take a look at the link I gave you you will see that local value comes first before "style - values".

Local values are very powerful.

That is why your Button will always be Orange even when disabled. The property system will try to find a value for the background when your trigger fires and it will always find the local one because that is the value with the highest prority.

In order to make this work properly you will have to use SetCurrentValue instead of SetValue when setting the value of Button's background. (Means you will have to override Buttons code)

Take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx

This method is used by a component that programmatically sets the value of one of its own properties without disabling an application's declared use of the property. The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will continue to work.

**Edit:**

Example to understand dependency property value precedence and hit testing.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="20" Margin="40" Text="asdfasdfa" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Rectangle  Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Then there is no way to actualy change the background using only the template? That's a bummer, I freaking hate how it goes gray by disabling it, so I thought making my own button would solve it...

Comment: Hi, have you solved your issue? Yes there is a way but either using SetCurrentValue or by tricking a little bit.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I've read what you provided so far, but I failed to make it work.

Comment: I posted you an example. Take a look at my edit. If you understand this you will know how to solve your problem. Feel free to ask any questions about the example I will give you.

Comment: Well yeah, I understand your example and tried it out, but the same problem remains, since I want the style to work even when the user defines a background. In other words, in your code when I define a background it doesn't change the colour of it that the triggers fire due to the Precedence List.

Comment: @StevenBorges You havent understood my example. Take a look again exactly when does the Grid color changes.

Comment: I see that the trigger binded to the grid turns the rectangle yellow, and that the textbox trigger doesn't work. Altough I don't understand why it yellows the frame outside the rectangle. I'm feeling dumb right now for not getting what you're trying to tell me...

Comment: @StevenBorges It happens to be that somebody else also tried out the same I did in the example I gave you. Check this link out please: http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hit-testing-in-wpf/ No need to feel bad about this. Feel free to ask as many questions as you want. I will get you to there so you know how to solve this issue. Though in order to achive this you will need to first understand the examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [DependecyProperty value precedence order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) you will see that setting a value explicitly (treated as local value) on a control will override any values set by the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: the `Background` property is of type `Brush`, so you should write

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...>
    ...
</Border>
```

instead of

```
<Border ...>
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </Border.Background>
    ...
</Border>
```

Comment: Dunno why I did that, changed!