# How can I bind a Polygon Fill property to the Background property of the button?

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have created a HexagonButton by using Styles and ControlTemplates. At this moment the HexagonButton background is blue.

I would like to have possibility to set its background color at the moment of loading the button or at least when put it to the canvas. Unfortunaty when I put button to the canvas and try to change Background to other color for example to Red all effects connected to IsMouseOver, IsPressed do not work.

Is it possible to connect this

```
<Polygon x:Name="HexagonPolygon" Points="1,0 0.50046, 0.86576 -0.50046, 0.86576 -1,0 -0.50046,-0.86576 0.50046,-0.86576" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

with this

```
        <Button Name ="OO" Width="100" Height="100"  Background ="Red" Canvas.Left="176" Canvas.Top="120" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

I don't really understand how I could solve my problem and need some advise to continue my attempts in right direction. Should I create a user control or something like that?

Or may be it is possible to solve this problem with DynamicResources, but how.

Here is the whole code.

```
<Window x:Class="ForthHexagonButtonWR.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ForthHexagonButtonWR"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Key="HighlightBackground"  >
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop  Color="Blue" Offset=".6" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>

        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Key="PressedBackground">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop  Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultBackground" Color="Blue" ></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" x:Key="DisabledBackground"></SolidColorBrush>

        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Key="Border">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>

        <!-- The style that applies the button control template. -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <Polygon x:Name="HexagonPolygon" Points="1,0 0.50046, 0.86576 -0.50046, 0.86576 -1,0 -0.50046,-0.86576 0.50046,-0.86576" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Border}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBackground}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"> 
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBackground}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackground}"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Canvas>
    <Button Name ="OO" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="176" Canvas.Top="120" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O1" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="176" Canvas.Top="34" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O2" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="76" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O3" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="251" Canvas.Top="162" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O4" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="177" Canvas.Top="206" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O5" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="103" Canvas.Top="162" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="O6" Width="100" Height="100"  Canvas.Left="101" Canvas.Top="76" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `Background` for your Button from outside, the Style trigger setter inside won't be able to change the `Background` because of [DependencyProperty value precedence](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjX3tvIrKTIAhXi46YKHaLBCpg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2Fms743230(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGMSO4IIv2O0gOK0YvJ8mQRqAFZBQ&sig2=6l34W2YM_bXT16Yjd55YhQ&bvm=bv.104226188,bs.1,d.dGY) (the local setting will override the setting via Style in this case).

So you should change the `Fill` of the internal Polygon directly, instead of the `Background` of the templated parent (Button). However you need to move all Triggers into the `ControlTemplate` (using ControlTemplate's Triggers instead of Style's Triggers):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                    <Polygon x:Name="HexagonPolygon" Points="1,0 0.50046, 0.86576 -0.50046, 0.86576 -1,0 -0.50046,-0.86576 0.50046,-0.86576" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter TargetName="HexagonPolygon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBackground}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"> 
                           <Setter TargetName="HexagonPolygon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PressedBackground}" />
                         </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                           <Setter TargetName="HexagonPolygon" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackground}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Border}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}"></Setter>            
    </Style>
```

We use `TargetName` of a `Setter` to indicate which element (inside the ControlTemplate's scope) having the property to be set.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might be overlaying the background with the background you define while loading your control. Please see already posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770336/trigger-wont-change-background).

You might need to use `DynamicResource` for working the things out.