# WPF: The custom style is not working after changed the button background color

Tags: wpf, styles

After I clicked the button, the button's background color will always red. I hope the "isMouseOver" trigger still working.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

```
private void onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            button.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Trigger won't change Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770336/trigger-wont-change-background)

Basically you have style values declared for background in your triggers but then you set a local value for background in your button's click handler. Local values will take precedence over style values.

One option is to change background for IsPressed trigger instead of doing it from your click handler:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

Technically you could do this a few other ways but that is likely the cleanest.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. I find another solution: button.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);